ContentView media causing unwanted results
In my SwiftUI ContentView, I have a media view with an image or video that should have rounded corners. However, the media often loses its rounded corners at the bottom and appears cut off. I've tried multiple adjustments to the layout without success.
I suspect it may have something to do with layering or how the caption section affects the media display. Here is a screenshot illustrating the issue:

I've tried fixing it using ZStack and other layout adjustments, but the problem persists. Here is the relevant portion of my code:
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

// MARK: - MediaView
struct MediaView: View {
    let fileName: String
    let profilePicFileName: String
    let username: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                if let profilePicUrl = MediaStorageManager.shared.loadMedia(fileName: profilePicFileName) {
                    AsyncImage(url: profilePicUrl) { image in
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                            .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("N/A")
                        .font(.system(size: 10))
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                }

                Text(username)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding([.horizontal, .top], 20)

            // Main media display section
            ZStack {
                Group {
                    if fileName.contains(".mp4") {
                        if let videoURL = MediaStorageManager.shared.loadMedia(fileName: fileName) {
                            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: videoURL))
                                .aspectRatio(9 / 16, contentMode: .fill)
                                .frame(width: 360, height: 590)
                                .cornerRadius(15)
                                .clipped()
                        } else {
                            Text("Video file not found")
                        }
                    } else {
                        if let imageURL = MediaStorageManager.shared.loadMedia(fileName: fileName) {
                            AsyncImage(url: imageURL) { image in
                                image
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
                                    .frame(width: 360, height: 590)
                                    .cornerRadius(15)
                                    .clipped()
                            } placeholder: {
                                ProgressView()
                            }
                        } else {
                            Text("Image file not found")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 20)
    }
}


// MARK: - ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var refreshID = UUID()  // Used to force-refresh the TabView

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {  // Make the whole UI scrollable
                VStack {
                    TabView {
                        ForEach(viewModel.mediaUrls, id: \.self) { fileName in
                            MediaView(fileName: fileName,
                                      profilePicFileName: viewModel.profilePicUrl,  // Pass profile picture filename directly
                                      username: viewModel.username)
                        }
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                    .frame(height: 600)
                    .id(refreshID)

                    interactionDetails
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        pasteButton
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: viewModel.mediaUrls) { oldValue, newValue in
                    refreshID = UUID()  // Force TabView update
                    print("Old URLs: \(oldValue)")
                    print("New URLs: \(newValue)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var pasteButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            viewModel.handlePasteButtonAction()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
        }
        .tint(.green)
    }

    private var interactionDetails: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "heart")
                Text("\(viewModel.likeCount)")
                Image(systemName: "bubble.right")
                Text("\(viewModel.commentCount)")
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.top, 5)

            Divider()
            
            Text(viewModel.captionText)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .padding(.all, 10)
        }
        .frame(height: 120)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .frame(width: 360)
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .padding(.top, 20)
    }
}

How can I maintain the rounded corners on my media while keeping the caption section directly below it without causing clipping or overlap?
Code update:
// MARK: - ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: InstagramViewModel
    @State private var refreshID = UUID()  // Used to force-refresh the TabView

    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        // Convert to an array to maintain unique values and use it with ForEach
                        ForEach(Array(Set(viewModel.mediaUrls)), id: \.self) { fileName in
                            MediaView(fileName: fileName,
                                      profilePicFileName: viewModel.profilePicUrl,  // Pass profile picture filename directly
                                      username: viewModel.username)
                        }
                        interactionDetails
                    }
                }
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                .id(refreshID)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        pasteButton
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: viewModel.mediaUrls) { oldValue, newValue in
                    refreshID = UUID()  // Force TabView update
                    print("Old URLs: \(oldValue)")
                    print("New URLs: \(newValue)")
                }
            }
        }
    }


Can you include a [mre]?

Note, NavigationView is deprecated, you should use NavigationStack.
TabView should be top most, with NavigationStack inside.
You should also declare or pass a viewModel to your ContentView and
ensure that viewModel.mediaUrls are unique in the ForEach.

so I updated the code as you mentioned, can see above and now the tabview is stacking my images vertically as if it was in social media apps. It no longer scrolls side to side. @workingdogsupportUkraine

to scroll side to side, use ScrollView(.horizontal) {...} and HStack

the issue is swapping through the tabview medias. Lets say I have 5 photos, in this current code they stack vertically on top of each other, like in instagram. I need them to stack horizontally like previously .tabViewStyle(.page) https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-scrolling-pages-of-content-using-tabviewstyle @workingdogsupportUkraine
